# the C, what does "void main (int argc, char *argv[0])", note the zero in argv

Tags: c

Speaking of C
I know that

```
void main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

is the correct way to pass arguments to main,
but out of curiosity i wrote

```
void main (int argc, char *argv[1])
```

and the program, after compilation showed the exact same result as previous one.
What exactly i did in second version, can somebody explain me that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to execute the second version with 2 or 3 arguments

Comment: @ThomasAyoub What do you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void main (int argc, char *argv[1])
```

and

```
void main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

are equivalent.

`argv` is a pointer (`char**`) and the size specified for it in `main()` is not the actual size of strings in `argv` -- because an array passed to a function gets converted into a pointer to its first element. Basically the size value is ignored by the compiler.

For the same reason, you can specify:

```
void main (int argc, char *argv[101])
```

and it will still work as you'd expect.
It can be confusing for anyone reading the code. But it's perfectly valid.

Relevant post: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: A small correction. the size value **of the last dimension** is ignored by the compiler. No difference in this case, but in the sake of preciseness might worth a fix.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh that is not strictly true. In the function `foo(int array[][16])` it is the last dimension that the compiler *does* need to know.

Comment: It'd be unambiguous to say *leftmost dimension is ignored*.

Comment: is it up to compiler to allow such declaration?

Comment: @user3694243 This is *decaying* is guaranteed by C standard and so, compiler obliges (not specific to any particular compiler/platform).

Answer (score 0):

**First**, speaking of C, return type of `main()` should be `int`.
This is from the C language standard:

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
>   1. The function called at program startup is named `main`. **The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function**. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
>   parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

**Second**, `char *argv[]` is there to allow for multiple command line arguments. Although `char *argv[0]` looks strange but valid, it is common to leave to your command line argument parser dealing with this programmatically.
Here is a code example demonstrating that `char *argv[0]` does not affect command line argument parsing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[0])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are both equivalent to `T *a`; they declare `a` as a pointer to `T`.

In the case of `argv`, `T` is `char *`.

If `T` is an array type `R [M]`, then `R a[N][M]` and `R a[][M]` are equivalent to `R (*a)[M]`; they declare `a` as a pointer to an array of `R`.